# Always redirected to the login page

Tags: symfony

I have following issue. In my app exists an login and sign in page. If a user click on the "sign in" link the user is always redirected to the login page.

I defined the path for the sign in page in my "access_control" in "security.yml" like so:

```
- { path: ^/user/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
```

I look to the http headers and found a redirect "302", but i can't find any code section in my app with this redirect. I don't know why the redirect is executed , can someone give me a hint?

```
GET /app_dev.php/user/register HTTP/1.1
Host: app.dev-local
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: PHPSESSID=j7enuu35aguids9e0bqc4at195
Referer: http://app.dev-local/app_dev.php/login
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 03 Mar 2015 06:36:27 GMT
Location: http://app.dev-local/app_dev.php/login
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Debug-Token: 0ec022
X-Debug-Token-Link: /app_dev.php/_profiler/0ec022
```

Update my "security.yml" with "signup" firewall:

```
security:
    access_decision_manager:
        strategy: unanimous
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        secured_area:
            pattern:   ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login_check
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                success_handler: app_user_handler_login
                failure_handler: app_user_handler_login
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /login
            switch_user: {role: ROLE_ADMIN}
        signup:
            pattern:  ^/user/register
            anonymous: true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/scale, roles: ROLE_WISA }
        - { path: ^/scale/add, roles: ROLE_WISA }
        - { path: ^/scale/edit, roles: ROLE_WISA }
        - { path: ^/scale/delete, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/scale/activate, roles: ROLE_WISA }
        - { path: ^/scale/deactivate, roles: ROLE_WISA }
        - { path: ^/questionnaire, roles: ROLE_WISA }
        - { path: ^/questionnaire/add, roles: ROLE_WISA }
        - { path: ^/questionnaire/edit, roles: ROLE_WISA }
        - { path: ^/questionnaire/delete, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/questionnaire/activate, roles: ROLE_WISA }
        - { path: ^/questionnaire/deactivate, roles: ROLE_WISA }
        - { path: ^/roles, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/roles/add, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/roles/edit, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/user, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
        - { path: ^/user/add, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/user/edit, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
        - { path: ^/user/delete, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/user/show-profile, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
        - { path: ^/user/deactivate, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/user/activate, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/user/absense/archive, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
        - { path: ^/user/password/change, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
        - { path: ^/user/loginhistory, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
        - { path: ^/school, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
        - { path: ^/school/add, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/school/deactivate, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/school/activate, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/school/delete, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/school/edit, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/school/profile, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
        - { path: ^/institution, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
        - { path: ^/institution/add, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/institution/deactivate, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/institution/activate, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/institution/delete, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/institution/edit, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/district/add, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/district/edit, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/district, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
        - { path: ^/district/deactivate, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/district/activate, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
        - { path: ^/district/delete, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/exclusion-periods/add, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/exclusion-periods/edit, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/exclusion-periods, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
        - { path: ^/exclusion-periods/deactivate, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/exclusion-periods/activate, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
        - { path: ^/exclusion-periods/delete, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/municipality/edit, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/municipality/add, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/municipality, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
        - { path: ^/municipality/delete, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/permissions-category/add, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/permissions-category/edit, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/permissions-category, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/permissions-category/deactivate, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/permissions-category/activate, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/permissions-category/delete, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/permissions/add, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/permissions/edit, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/permissions, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/permissions/deactivate, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/permissions/activate, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/permissions/delete, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/province/add, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/province/edit, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/province, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
        - { path: ^/province/deactivate, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/province/activate, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
        - { path: ^/province/delete, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/schooltype/add, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/schooltype/edit, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/schooltype, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
        - { path: ^/schooltype/deactivate, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/schooltype/activate, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/schooltype/delete, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/languages/add, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/languages/edit, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/languages/activate, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/languages/deactivate, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/languages/delete, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/languages, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/projects/add, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/projects/edit, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/projects, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
        - { path: ^/projects/deactivate, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/projects/activate, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/projects/delete, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/characteristics/add, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/characteristics/edit, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/characteristics, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
        - { path: ^/characteristics/deactivate, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/characteristics/activate, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
        - { path: ^/characteristics/delete, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/user/import, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/user/export, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/school/import, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/school/export, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/userdocumentation/edit, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
        - { path: ^/userdocumentation/add, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
        - { path: ^/userdocumentation, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
        - { path: ^/userdocumentation/activate, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/userdocumentation/deactivate, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
        - { path: ^/userdocumentation/delete, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/application-ajax/school/list, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
        - { path: ^/application-ajax/school/province, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
        - { path: ^/application-ajax/school/municipality, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
        - { path: ^/application-ajax/school/branch, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
        - { path: ^/application-ajax/schooltype/branch, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
        - { path: ^/application-ajax/district/province, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
        - { path: ^/application-ajax/province/municipality, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
        - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/languages/change, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/application-ajax/password/generate$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
        - { path: ^/blank, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }

    providers:
        administrators:
            entity: { class: appUserBundle:User, property: username }

    encoders:
        app\UserBundle\Entity\User: 
            algorithm: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_USER: ~
        ROLE_STUDENT: [ROLE_USER]
        ROLE_TEACHER: [ROLE_USER]
        ROLE_SCHOOL: [ROLE_USER]
        ROLE_MAB_MA: [ROLE_USER]
        ROLE_WISA: [ROLE_MAB_MA]
        ROLE_HEADMASTER: [ROLE_USER]
        ROLE_SCHOOL_PARENTS_COUNCIL: [ROLE_USER]
        ROLE_CLERK: [ROLE_MAB_MA]
        ROLE_JUNIOR_CONSULTANT: [ROLE_MAB_MA]
        ROLE_SENIOR_CONSULTANT: [ROLE_MAB_MA]
        ROLE_EXTERNAL_TEAMLEADER: [ROLE_MAB_MA]
        ROLE_INTERNAL_TEAMLEADER: [ROLE_MAB_MA]
        ROLE_TEAMLEADER: [ROLE_EXTERNAL_TEAMLEADER, ROLE_INTERNAL_TEAMLEADER]
        ROLE_SCHOOL_SUPERVISORY: [ROLE_MAB_MA]
        ROLE_SCHOOLOPERATOR: [ROLE_MAB_MA]
        ROLE_CLERK_CONTROLLER: [ROLE_TEAMLEADER, ROLE_CLERK]
        ROLE_EDITOR: [ROLE_CLERK_CONTROLLER, ROLE_SCHOOL_SUPERVISORY, ROLE_TEACHER, ROLE_STUDENT, ROLE_JUNIOR_CONSULTANT, ROLE_SENIOR_CONSULTANT, ROLE_WISA, ROLE_HEADMASTER, ROLE_SCHOOL_PARENTS_COUNCIL, ROLE_SCHOOLOPERATOR]
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_EDITOR]
```

Now i solve my issue :) The problem was that i have a route "/user" in my access_control area. This include also the url "user/register". I change my url name to "/signup". Now the issue is solved for me, many thanks for your support

Comment: Can you show the whole `security.yml` file? This is probably a misconfiguration of some route.

Comment: @i-am-michiel i add the whole security.yml

Comment: `- { path: ^/user/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}` seems to not be in your security.yml, are you sure that you have included it?

Comment: @doncallisto this is the third to last in the "access_control" part. Or do you mean a different area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your login form is not accessible for non-connected users.

Check this line :

```
secured_area:
        pattern:   ^/
```

Which means all url patterns except "/" require a connected user. Including the signup form. You might want to add a specific firewall for the sign-up form.

Just add a specific firewall for the signup form :

```
signup:
        pattern:  ^/user/register
        anonymous: true
```

EDIT : As stated in my comment, the order has some importance. When you define a list of paths, as in your example, the first matching path will be used.

```
- { path: ^/user, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
- { path: ^/user/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
```

You should limit your paths :

```
- { path: ^/user$, roles: ROLE_MAB_MA }
```

AS `/user/register` will actually be matched by `^/user`.

Comment: @i-am-michiel Now i create a specific firewall "signup" for the route "/user/register". If i place the new firewall over the existing "secured_area" and call the url for sign up, i get the exception "Full authentication is required to access this resource". And if i place the "signup" firewall under the "secured_area" the redirect to login page appears again. I also clear the apc cache, the file and browser cache.

Comment: The security component uses the first firewall matching the pattern. If you place it under the existing firewall, it will not be used.

Comment: @i-am-michiel ok now I understand better, thank you for your support